# Targeting Xpath attributes in Selenium

Tags: python, html, xml, selenium, web-scraping

I'm using Selenium to scrape a Web Page and I'm having some problems targeting some attributes.

The page I'm trying to scrape looks like this:

```
<div>
    <span abc> content </span>
    <span def> content2 </span>
<div>
```

My goal would be to retrieve the text within the "span abc" tag, without selecting the other text included in the "span def" tag.

I've tried multiple approaches and looked at a lot of different resources but I wasn't able to find the right approach, since I don't want to select all the spans at the same time and I don't want to search based on the text within the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach would be indexing cause you do not want to select based on

> since I don't want to select all the spans at the same time and I
> don't want to search based on the text within the tags.

If abc is an attribute please use :

```
//div/span[@abc]
```

or

with indexing :

```
(//div/span[@abc])[1]
```

Comment: Thanks , your first line is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to pull the first span out of these two, you could easily do this with the XPATH. It would look like this:

```
span = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/span[1]").text
```

if you want to pull every span, but execute commands with each of these you could do:

```
span = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div/span"))
m = 1

while m <= 0:
    span = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/span["+str(m)+"]")
    print(span.text)

    m = m + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use xpath like `//span[1]/text()` for get text inside of the `<span>` tag

```
span = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/span[1]/text()")
```